# Javascript clearInterval() deducts another 1 second when trying to pause

Tags: javascript

I have built a recorder with timer of 15 seconds which works fine on start and stop. But when we pause the recording, the recording pauses but the timer deducts another 1 second before stopping.

Following is the js code where I am doing this stuff of getting the recorder state and doing clearInterval(countDown) in it.

p.s I have also tried putting timeSecond inside else

```
    const countDown = setInterval(() => {

  displayTime(timeSecond);
  if (timeSecond == 0 || timeSecond < 1) {
    endCount();
    clearInterval(countDown);
  }  
  if (recorder && recorder.state === 'paused') {
  
  clearInterval(countDown)
}
  else{
  timeSecond--;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```js
const countDown = setInterval(() => {

  displayTime(timeSecond);
  if (timeSecond == 0 || timeSecond < 1) {
    endCount();
    clearInterval(countDown);
  }  
  if (recorder && recorder.state === 'paused') {
  
  clearInterval(countDown)
}
  timeSecond--;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: It clears the interval, and continues to timeSecond--, does what its wrtten to do, protect that with an if/else and you should be fine

Comment: Yes I did try that by putting timeSecond-- inside else But that way we're skipping another second if the recorder.state is not pause

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the function.

setInterval will start one unit after it is called

And you need to leave the function if you do not want it to fall through to the  timeSecond--;

```js
const output = document.getElementById("time");
const displayTime = time => output.textContent = time;
const endCount = () => output.textContent = "done";
let timeSecond = 5;
let tId;
const recorder = { state: "" }
const countDown = ()=> {
  displayTime(timeSecond);
  if (timeSecond < 1) {
    endCount();
    clearInterval(tId);
    return;
  }
  if (recorder && recorder.state === 'paused') {
    clearInterval(tId);
    return;
  }
  timeSecond--;
};  
countDown()
tId = setInterval(countDown,1000);
```

```html
<span id="time">Hello</span>
```

Comment: Still giving me a difference. If I don't pause I am getting the full length of bars. if I pause, the length is shorter

Comment: Please post more html and code. I cannot guess what you have

Comment: This is a voice recorder. Rest of the code is not worth reading to solve this issue. In Html I have simply added a div with id timer which I am getting and replacing the inner html content with the code in js

Comment: Can you add your pause thing though-  that is what you say does not work

Comment: It works, the timer pauses when we click on button. But due to the 1 second interval the timer subtracts another 1 second when we pause the timer